# Incoming voice mail notification

Tags: android

Any way to receive notification on incoming voice mail?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way for that yet...because Incoming call notification comes from
RIL(Radio Interface Layer) with AsyncResult object in handler of Phone class and for security reasons...phone package that does have access at application level. (Otherwise CallManager and CallNotifier classes would have provided you the information for new incoming call).

Secondly new incoming call do not have intent kind of notification like in case of outgoing call.
So no way...